# How do I insert new line characters to a string when entered in an input box

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to replace substrings. The substitution is entered in an input box. The thing is that I am unable to insert `\n` via the input box.

So this does not work

```
var val = document.getElementById('val').innerHTML;
var replacement = document.getElementById('replaceWith').value
val.innerHTML = val.innerHTML.replace(reg, replacement + '$&');
```

But this does work

```
var val = document.getElementById('val').innerHTML;
var replacement = document.getElementById('replaceWith').value
    val.innerHTML = val.innerHTML.replace(reg, "\n" + '$&');
```

Is there a way to accomplish this?

Comment: You need to define a kind of a special newline representation. If you are OK with ``\n``, just use `replacement.replace(/\\n/g, "\n")`

Comment: `input type="text"` is for single line text. `textarea` is what you want.

Comment: If the linked questions don't solve your problem, your question may not be clear. If that's the case, please update your question with a [mcve] demonstrating the problem, ideally a **runnable** one using Stack Snippets (the `[<>]` toolbar button; [here's how to do one](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/)).

Comment: @Wiktor That almost worked but. It does insert a new line but also quotation marks

Comment: Oh, you must have pasted my code in a wrong way.